# How to split a UnicodeString in C++Builder

Tags: c++, split, c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

In C++ Builder (10.3 in my case), I don't know how to work with their types (in this case, their `System::UnicodeString`). I don't know how to split that or simply just get a standard C++ string that I could split.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString)? `UnicodeString` has a [`Pos()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString.Pos) method for searching for the position of a substring, and a [`SubString()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString.SubString) method for extracting a substring given its position and count. Very similar to the `find()` and `substr()` methods of `std::wstring`. Also see [Unicode in RAD Studio](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Unicode_in_RAD_Studio)

Comment: @RemyLebeau i wanted to split a string to words and doing it like that seemed fastidious to me, but i guess i will have to do a loop around with that. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If you [define the `VCL_IOSTREAM` conditional during compiling](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B_Compiler_Directories_and_Conditionals), that will enable `operator>>` for `UnicodeString`, then you can use a standard [`std::wistringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to read whitespace-separated words into `UnicodeString` variables, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`SplitString`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.StrUtils.SplitString) function.

It returns an array of strings of type [`System.Types.TStringDynArray`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Types.TStringDynArray) that contains the split parts of the original string.

Example outline:

```
#include <System.StrUtils.hpp>

// ...

{
  UnicodeString str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
  UnicodeString delims = ", ;.";

  DynamicArray<UnicodeString> split = SplitString(str, delims);

  for (int i = split.Low; i <= split.High; ++i)
    if (!split[i].IsEmpty())  // consecutive delimiters produce empty strings
    {
      /* word processing */
    }
}
```